# format file to remove " characters

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the following data

```
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20261031|"     "|3,827.92"     "|3,581.41"     "|542,729.62"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20261130|"     "|3,680.15"     "|3,729.18"     "|539,000.44"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20261231|"     "|3,776.70"     "|3,632.63"     "|535,367.81"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270131|"     "|3,751.24"     "|3,658.09"     "|531,709.72"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270228|"     "|3,365.07"     "|4,044.26"     "|527,665.46"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270331|"     "|3,697.28"     "|3,712.05"     "|523,953.41"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270430|"     "|3,552.84"     "|3,856.49"     "|520,096.92"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270531|"     "|3,644.24"     "|3,765.09"     "|516,331.83"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270630|"     "|3,501.16"     "|3,908.17"     "|512,423.66"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270731|"     "|3,590.47"     "|3,818.86"     "|508,604.80"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270831|"     "|3,563.72"     "|3,845.61"     "|504,759.19"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20270930|"     "|3,422.68"     "|3,986.65"     "|500,772.54"   "MBA"
"MG1507XXXXXX|" "|020000XXXXXX" "20271031|"     "|3,508.84"     "|3,900.49"     "|496,872.05"   "MBA"
```

How ever i want to change it so it will look like

```
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20261031|3,827.92|3,581.41|542,729.62|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20261130|3,680.15|3,729.18|539,000.44|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20261231|3,776.70|3,632.63|535,367.81|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270131|3,751.24|3,658.09|531,709.72|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270228|3,365.07|4,044.26|527,665.46|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270331|3,697.28|3,712.05|523,953.41|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270430|3,552.84|3,856.49|520,096.92|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270531|3,644.24|3,765.09|516,331.83|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270630|3,501.16|3,908.17|512,423.66|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270731|3,590.47|3,818.86|508,604.80|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270831|3,563.72|3,845.61|504,759.19|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20270930|3,422.68|3,986.65|500,772.54|MBA|
MG1507XXXXXX|020000XXXXXX|20271031|3,508.84|3,900.49|496,872.05|MBA|
```

I am not sure what to use to achieve this. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in a file named 'data':

```
sed -e s'/^"//' -e 's/|" "|/|/g' -e 's/" "|/|/g' -e 's/" "/|/g' -e s'/"$/|/' data
```

Answer (score 3):

You could `tr`anslate all spaces and double quotes to `|` (and `s`queeze) then `cut` from the 2nd character to the end of line:

```
tr -s '[[:blank:]"]' \| <infile | cut -c2-
```

Comment: Could you explain how `cut -c2-` acts like `cut --complement -c1`?

Comment: @Fiximan -  `-c2-` is standard i.e. `-c` followed by _LIST_ - in this case one range: `N-` meaning  _from N'th character to end of line_. `--complement` is a GNU extension: _Select for printing the complement of the characters selected with the ‘-c’ option. In other words, do not print the characters specified via that option_.

Comment: I wasn't aware one could use half-bounded intervals for ranges in `cut` - thanks.

Comment: Why not `tr -s '[[:blank:]"]' \| <infile` ?

Comment: @Costas - lol, because too tired I guess, thanks for the heads-up !

Answer (score 1):

```
sed -i 's/\"//g' filename
```

You can escape the `"` character by putting a `\`.  In case you want to remove all spaces as well, do the following:

```
sed -i 's/[" ]//g' filename
```

Comment: No. You don't want to escape `"`. `"` is not special in sed. On the other hand, `\"` may be special with some `sed` implementations. For instance, `\'` is special in GNU `sed` (means end-of-string even with the `m` flag is used).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
sed -e 's/["| ]\+/|/g' -e 's/^|//' < file
```

The first expression will replace each block containing one or more |, ", or spaces with a single |. The second will remove the | at the start of each line.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`

```
awk ' BEGIN { FS="[|\" ]+" ; OFS="|" } { print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"|" } ' file
```

Explanation:

`BEGIN { FS="[|\" ]+" ; OFS="|" }` first set the following:

`FS="[|\" ]+"`: fields are separated by any combination (`+`) (zero or more of any) of the set (`[]`) pipe, double quotes (need to be escaped) and space `|\"`.

`OFS="|"` separate the output fields with pipes.

`print $2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7,$8"|"` print columns 1 through 8 and a pipe at the end (note that it is shifted by one as the lines start with double quotes making the first field an empty string and thus shifting the position of all others).